# How to call AlertDialog inside AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have this code:

```
public class Example
{
 String sp,st;
 SQLiteDatabase database, database2;
 void func()
 {
 new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .setTitle("Confirm")
    .setMessage("Are you sure?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      String st = editTextSt.getText().toString();
      String sp = editTextSp.getText().toString();
      database2 = new SQLiteDbHelper(this);
      database = database2.getWritableDatabase();
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(SQLiteDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_SP, sp);
      values.put(SQLiteDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_ST, st);
      long insertId = database.insert(SQLiteDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
      //I would like to call it here
    }})
    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
    .show();

 }
```

I would like to call this AlertDialog inside the AlertDialog above:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Saved!")
                .setNeutralButton("OK", null)
                .show();
```

How can I do it?

If I just put it where I want to, I get error that "The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(Example.this)
                .setMessage("Saved!")
                .setNeutralButton("OK", null)
                .show();
```

This will work assuming that the class `Example` is an `Activity`.

**i.e.**:

```
public class Example extends Activity
```

**Otherwise, use this**:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
                .setMessage("Saved!")
                .setNeutralButton("OK", null)
                .show();
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly! I think this is the first time I didn't try doing that. Hate to be noob.

Answer (score 0):

Once you are inside the ClickListener object `this` is going to refer to that object rather than the activity like it does outside of there assuming `Example` is an Activity which it may not be based on your code.

To fix it you just need to use a different way to get the context to pass in to your builder consstructor.

to create the first builder that you use you did it like this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
```

using `view.getContext()` to get the context that you need. You should be able to do it the same way with your second builder.

Comment: no, "Cannot refer to a non-final variable view inside an inner class defined in a different method"

Comment: @JohnnyAlmi where do you get `view` from? Try making it final. Also I strongly suggest you brush up on your Java programming before you dive into Android too far. That is a common issue that you'd know how to fix if you practice your plain Java more. Trying to work on Android without good java fundamentals is just going to cause frustration.

Comment: The other answer is working. Thank you for your time! I have good C/C++/C# and basic Java knowledge, but it gets stuck from time to time. I will definately improve my Java knowledge!